Flexbox width calculation when wrapping children
I have a flexbox with a varying amount of children. All children have the same size (i.e., 96px). The flexbox has wrapping enabled.
When all children fit in the same row, the flexbox's reported width is less than what the parent offers (intended behaviour). However, as soon as wrapping happens, the flexbox always fills the entire parent.


.flex-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 8px;
    background-color: lightpink; /* for debugging */
}

.flex-item {
    text-align: center;
    width: 96px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    background-color: lightblue; /* for debugging */
}
<div style="width: 250px">
 <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">Child 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Child 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-container" style="margin-top: 32px">
      <div class="flex-item">Child 1</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Child 2</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Child 3</div>
  </div>
</div>



In this snippet you can see the behaviour: The first flexbox has a width less than the parent's width. The second one, however, expands to the parent's width, even though the children do not fill up the space on the right.
This is problematic because I want to center the flexbox inside its parent. And it seems impossible when its width matches the parent.
It is worth to note that I am preferably looking for a solution without JavaScript.

What type of behavior do you want the flexbox or flexbox items to have? Are you wanting them to take up the entirety of the space of the parent or to maintain the current behavior, but be centered within the container?

The intended behaviour is that the flexbox shrinks to the width actually being occupied by its children. This way I can center the entire flexbox. I don't want the flexbox items to be centered within the flexbox.
